# dot product between columns in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dot-product

I need to compute the dot product between columns of pandas dataframe and store the result in the different column. How this can be done.

```
column1 column2 column3    column4 column5 column6
   1       2       3           1      2       3
   4       5       6           4      5       6
```

suppose i need to compute dot product between 
column1, column2, column3 and column4
, column5, column6 i.e.

`column1 * column4 + column2 * column5 + column3 * column6`

and store the result in other column suppose df['dot'].

Then how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['dot'] = (df[['col1','col2','col3']].values * df[['col4,'col5','col6']].values).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
getting this error

Comment: @SatyamAnand probably you missed something. df[['col1','col2','col3']] - is not a list. Check your code on double brackets